# Docker service doesn't start after boot

Tags: docker, service, systemd

I am trying to figure out why my docker service doesn't run automatically on reboot.

Here it is:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry=some-registry
```

When I try:
`$ sudo systemctl enable docker.service`
nothing happens.

The status of this service under list-unit-files:

```
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep docker
docker.service           static
```

If I start the service manually (`sudo systemctl start docker.service`) it works as expected though.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you have not specified any target in your service. You should change the service file as below

```
$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry=some-registry

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that run the below commands

```
systemctl daemon-reload 
systemctl disable docker
systemctl enable docker
```

And restart the system

Comment: It is still not running :(

Comment: Try `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl disable docker; systemctl enable docker`

Comment: Yep it did the trick. The `systemctl enabled docker` after the change created the desired link. Please add it to your answer and I`ll accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` file does not exist for me. However, fortunately and apparently, my problem was solved through  `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl disable docker; systemctl enable docker`. I'm using docker version `19.03.6`